# testing parameter values with \ifx

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, debugging

Let's say that I would like to redefine `\@seccntformat` so that whenever the section counter is printed, it is prefixed by `Section`, but other counters should no be changed.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mytest{section}%
\def\myarg#1{#1}
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \ifx\myarg#1\mytest{Section}\fi%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}  % Should be printed as "Section 1  Foo"
\subsection{Bar}  % Should be printed as "1.1  Bar"
\end{document}
```

For some reason I can't manage to get `\myarg#1` and `\mytest` to compare equal when `#1` is `section`. Now this is my first time using `\ifx`, so I hope I'm missing something trivial.

I would appreciate some hints about how to debug such a macro.  Is there a way to see each intermediate expansion step and observe what arguments `\ifx` is actually receiving?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The conditional `\ifx` does no expansion and it compares the next two tokens. So in your test it compares `\myarg` with the first token in `#1`.

Therefore the test will be always false, because `#1` is the name of a section level counter.

Adding `\expandafter` before `\ifx` would not help, even adding braces around `#1`:

```
\expandafter\ifx\myarg{#1}\mytest
```

would become

```
\ifx section\mytest
```

which returns false, as it compares `s` with `e`.

You could use `\pdfstrcmp` (or, better, `\pdf@strcmp` with the `pdftexcmds` package):

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{section}=\z@
    Section % a space is wanted
  \fi
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{section}=\z@
    Section %
  \fi
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}  % Should be printed as "Section 1  Foo"
\subsection{Bar}  % Should be printed as "1.1  Bar"
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the attempt of doing the comparison with `\ifx` in the following way

```
\def\section@argument{section}
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \def\@argument{#1}%
  \ifx\@argument\section@argument
    Section %
  \fi
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

wouldn't work either. This is because `\@seccntformat` is passed through an `\edef` (in the form `\protected@edef`), so we'd get an error

```
Undefined control sequence
```

for `\@argument`. Adding `\noexpand` in front of `\@argument` wouldn't help, because the conditional is expanded during the `\edef`. This instead would work

```
\def\section@argument{section}
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \unexpanded{%
    \def\@argument{#1}%
    \ifx\@argument\section@argument
      Section %
    \fi
  }
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
```

because the argument to `\unexpanded` is not changed during an `\edef`, so it will be processed afterwards, when typesetting is involved.

Note that the `\protected@edef` is necessary because we must get the expansion of `\thesection` or `\thesubsection` at the moment the macro `\@seccntformat` is executed. An `\unexpanded` free solution is possible, by hiding the part in a macro:

```
\def\section@argument{section}
\def\check@section#1{%
   \def\@argument{#1}%
   \ifx\@argument\section@argument
     Section %
   \fi
}
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \noexpand\check@section{#1}%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

Comment: Using inner `\def`s was actually my first try, and I had to move them out of the macro because of the `Undefined control sequence` error which I did not understand.  Thank you for explaining that as well!