# Cleveref sorting issue for enumerate lists with crefalias

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297827/different-output-of-ref-and-cref-in-lists-with-enumitemcleveref) and on the useful answers, for each theorem environment I create a dedicated enumerate list which I "*crefalias*" to the theorem.
By doing so, when I cleve-refer to a list item, it prepends "*Theorem < number >*" to the item label (see the code and the picture below).

Everything works just fine, except that when I `\Cref` multiple items, it sorts them simply by the item counter without considering the theorem counter.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
    \Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
    % Crete a dedicated enumerate environment
    \newlist{enumthm}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[enumthm]{label=(\roman*),ref=\thethm(\roman*)}
    \crefalias{enumthmi}{thm} % alias 'enumthm' counter to thm

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This theorem has a list:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item First
    \item Second\label{Thm:Second}
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
Also this theorem has a list:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item Third\label{Thm:Third}
    \item Fourth
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

Sorted cleve-referencing: \Cref{{Thm:Second},{Thm:Third}}.
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

As you see, Theorem 2(i) precedes Theorem 1(ii) because it considers only the enumerate counters, **while I would like it to take the theorem counter into account as well.**
Is it doable?

Thanks

P.S.
Probably a workaround is documented in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239995/21001) but in case I don't know to adapt it to my case, and I would prefer a cleaner tex solution rather than a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `\crefalias` in the present context. Instead, I would (a) use `\Crefname` to define the singular and plural "labels" that `cleveref` should prefix to the `enumthmi`-level items and (b) load the `cleveref` package with the option `compress` (which disables automatic sorting).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[compress]{cleveref}  % <-- "compress" is new

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

% Create a dedicated enumerate environment
\newlist{enumthm}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumthm]{label=\textup{(\roman*)},ref=\thethm(\roman*)}
\Crefname{enumthmi}{Theorem}{Theorems} % <-- use \Crefname

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This theorem has a list:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item First
    \item Second\label{Thm:Second}
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
This theorem has a list too:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item Third\label{Thm:Third}
    \item Fourth
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

Unsorted clever cross-references: \Cref{Thm:Second,Thm:Third}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But `compress` then would affect globally `cleveref`, and sorting wouldn't work anyway, right?. Isn't there really a way around?

Comment: @AndreasT - I can't think of a way right now, but let me look into this matter a bit more later today.

Comment: Thank you very much, take your time, I'm not in a hurry :)

Comment: @AndreasT - I've tried to come up with a solution that doesn't require using the `compress` option, but no success. I have a feeling that the cross-referencing use case you've proposed falls into the "feature request" category. You may want to contact the author/maintainer of the `cleveref` package and ask him for a suggestion. He's very responsive to suggestions! For instance, he came up with the `\crefstripprefix` macro and added it to `cleveref` package in response to the posting [Crossreference in Ref Range ((1a-1e) to (1a-e))](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135151/5001).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will follow your suggestion and post a solution if the developer provides one.

Comment: I contacted the author; this issue will be appended to the long list of feature requests, though unlikely to be addressed in a close future :)